# Notepad++ - replace every first space of a line

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I know there are a lot of these types of questions but I can not find a way to alter one of the existing solutions for my problem.
My text file looks like this:

```
word<tab>word<space>words_with_spaces
```

I would like to replace every first space of each line with an html linebreak (br). Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: "Is there a simple way to do this?"  Yes, use RegEx (just like you tagged your question).  What have you tried already?  Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: I just recently started playing around with RegEx. In fact, yesterday. I got as far as searching for (.*?)[ ] and replacing with \1<br> and I was stuck at the "do it only once per line"-part. I got it thanks to the answers. Thanks for your response, too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use RegEx to search and replace.

In the search, type: `(.+?)[ ](.+)`
In the Replace field, type: `$1<br>$2`

Make sure you are not searching for \r \n (its a checkbox) otherwise it will do a multi-line search.

Answer (score 5):

It was a slightly tricky expression to find, but the following works:-

- Find: `^([^ ]*)`  [this is `^([^_]*)_`, showing space as underscore for display clarity]
- Replace: `\1<br>`

The search string is a line beginning with any number of non-space characters (marked as a subexpression) followed by a space (therefore the first on the line).

The replacement is the first subexpression (the leading non-spaces) followed by the string to replace the first space.

Comment: Having seen LPChip's answer, I should add that the `. matches newline` setting does not affect my solution. I tested with it set and again with it clear.

Comment: 2 different methods to achieve the same thing. I'll vote yours up as well as its just as good as my answer. :) I could've edited my answer to use the ^ operator so the multi-line search has no effect

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This one works, except it does not replace the space but puts the linebreak in front of it.

Comment: You must have put an extra space in the replacement string (the display with back-quotes is confusing). It works perfectly for me.