# How to replace the last space in a line with '|' character in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I couldn't find any sample question that solves my problem in Notepad++.

I have a string of *n* words in the following format in a Notepad++ text file:

```
       Word_1<**space_1**>words_with_spaces<**spaces**>Word_n-1<**space_n-1**>Word_n
```

I would like to replace *n-1*th space (**space_n-1**) with "|" character.

Similarly, I would like to replace the first space only (**space_1**) with "@" character

Comment: See [Notepad++: Replace last appearance of semicolon in every line?](https://superuser.com/q/1330592) - replace the semicolon with a space in the answer

Comment: See [Notepad++ - replace every first space of a line](https://superuser.com/q/1055976)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\S+)\h+(.+)\h+`
- Replace with: `$1@$2|`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(\S+)       # group 1, 1 or more non-spaces
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(.+)        # group 2, 1 or more any character but newline
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1        
@       # @ character
$2      # content of group 2
|       # | character
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]